Make a macro for pointer struct
I need to make a macro to typecast (right word?) pointer struct from a function parameter. This is my struct:
typedef struct _AppData {
    GtkWidget* toplevel; // main window
    GtkWidget* view; // column style view
    GtkWidget* entry_outdir; // output dir
    GtkWidget* entry_artist; // artist
    GtkWidget* entry_title; // title
    GtkWidget* entry_link; // link
    GtkWidget* check_jman; // bool for jman
    GtkWidget* menuitem_clear; // init states
    GtkWidget* menuitem_action; // play/stop menu item
} AppData, *PAppData;

somewhere in my code is used like this:
g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (cb_select_folder), pad);
void cb_select_folder (GtkButton* sender, gpointer user_data)
{
  PAppData pad = PAPPDATA(user_data); // typecast macro here
  const gchar* dirname = gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY(pad->entry_outdir));
  // ..
}

To create the macro I'm trying this:
#define PAPPDATA(_in_) (PAppData(_in_))

and I get error: expected ‘)’ before ‘user_data’
Any help?

The expression PAppData(_in_) is a C++ explicit conversion, not C. For C there's only one type of explicit conversion ("cast") and that's e.g. (PAppData) _in_. As your beginners C material should have taught you. But your beginners material should also have taught you that in C there's no need to cast to or from void * pointers, they are implicitly convertible to any other simple pointer type. So plain PAppData pad = user_data; would work just fine.

This is awful.  Do not use typedef to hide pointer nature.  In fact, consider avoiding typedefs altogether -- they are never required, and only occasionally do they clarify instead of obscuring.  As for macros, I can't imagine why anyone would want to use a macro to hide a simple typecast.  If you insist on doing that, though, then first write an example of the code you want, without using a macro, then use that as a basis for writing the macro.

See Is it a good idea to typedef pointers? — TL;DR, the answer is generally no, except perhaps for pointers to functions (which can be rather verbose otherwise).

@JohnBollinger "This is awful. Do not use typedef to hide pointer nature." -- What about GLIB's typedef void* gpointer;, is the use justified?

No, @yvs2014, it is not.

It's probably best - in general - not to typedef pointers. However, the library glib has been using the typedef (void*) gpointer; for decades now. And as such libraries building on glib/gobject such as gtk, what you are using, also use it. Sometimes, just go with the flow I suppose.

In C you don't have to cast a (void*) to it's final type.
When using glib, gpointer is a typedef for a void*. Hence, no casting is nessesary. You do need to be sure, that the type is correct, otherwise you're in trouble.
void cb_select_folder (GtkButton* sender, gpointer user_data)
{
  PAppData pad = user_data; // No cast Necessary.
  const gchar* dirname = gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY(pad->entry_outdir));
  // ..
}

The GTK_ENTRY(pad->entry_outdir), actually does a cast, but that is because it's casting between two different kinds of pointers, from GtkWidget* to GtkEntry*. In addition to the cast, It also does some runtime checking whether the GtkWidget* is actually a GtkEntry*, you probably get a runtime warning when doing this cast when pad->entry_outdir turns out to be pointing to something else than a GtkEntry. But in GObject speak, GtkEntry is a GtkWidget and GtkWidget is an GObject. You PAppData is a plain pointer to struct and not a GObject.

Thanks for the explination. I'm an autodidactic programmer.

@Joel and you've taught me a new word. Thank you!

Type-casting happens this way:
(PAppData) _in_

Now surround them with parenthesis:
((PAppData) (_in_))

And now the macro should work. Your original macro was using a C++ cast.
Assuming gpointer is a void *, there's no need of a cast, as there's an implicit conversion to and from a void * in C. I also don't see why you need a macro here. This works:
PAppData pad = (PAPPDATA)user_data; # No macro required

Edit: According to the documentation:

gpointer
typedef void* gpointer;
An untyped pointer. gpointer looks better and is easier to use than void*.

So the cast can be elided. And as Jonathan Leffer has mentioned in the comments, see: Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?.
Also note the documentation states:

The standard C void * type should usually be preferred in new code, but gpointer can be used in contexts where a type name must be a single word, such as in the GType name of G_TYPE_POINTER or when generating a family of function names for multiple types using macros.


Also make a habit of surrounding _in_ with parens. Macros can be fed anything, and parentheses are free in C.

I'd add some reference to glib doc with its own note on gpointer use:
The standard C void * type should usually be preferred in new code, but gpointer can be used in contexts where a type name must be a single word, such as in the GType name of G_TYPE_POINTER or when generating a family of function names for multiple types using macros. taken from https://docs.gtk.org/glib/types.html#gpointer

@yvs2014 I guess that wasn't the first resource I found. Thank you very much. Answer updated.
